# Only in Token URL endpoint, the Client ID and Client Secret are being sent as request parameters in Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, openid-connect

In my application, I am using keycloak with the Authorization server that I have created in Spring Boot application. I have implemented authentication and authorization using OpenID Connect. In  Client Authentication parameter in keycloak, I have selected client_secret_post option. The configuration can be seen in the image below: [image]

In my Authorization server that I have developed in spring boot, I have also done the same thing. [image]

Now when I debug the code, I can see that with token request http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/token, the client id and client secret are sent in request paramrters as can be seen in the image below[image]

But with the userinfo request http://auth-server:9000/userinfo, I see that the client id and client secret are not sent in request parameters instead the client id and client secret are decoded and sent in the authorization Header as can be seen in the image below[image]

Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something? Why the client_id and client_secret are not being sent as request parameters for the userinfo endpoint URL http://auth-server:9000/userinfo also?

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak is an authorization-server. Don't create an other one.

Your Spring applications should be configured as either:

- resource-server for REST APIs. Tutorials [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)
- client for UIs (spring applications serving Thymeleaf pages, as well as native mobile apps and rich clients written with Angular, React, Vue, etc.). Use an OIDC client lib for that. `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` is to be used for Spring clients (like those with Thymeleaf), [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) with Angular, etc.

Comment: yes, we have micro services in which we have rest APIs and they are acting as resource servers. They validate token when we hit the resource server API. We have configured an OpenID Connect identity provider in keycloak. This OpenID Connect identity provider points to the authorization server. I have not created this architecture by the way. This architecture  has been created by another company and I am trying to integrate their services with my application.

Comment: The reason to integrate a separate OpenID Connect identity provider is that our authorization server executes some policies in another service. When these policies are executed, some credentials of user are fetched from which user details are extracted that we use for authentication and authorization purpose. We have not hardcoded usernames and passwords in keycloak.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know you can have Keycloak directly use your user database, right? And that you can write Spring access control rules from JWTs delivered by Keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I have figured it out. When User Info URL endpoint http://auth-server:9000/userinfo is triggered, in the the authorization header actually token is sent that has been retrieved from the token endpoint http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/token. So this is the expected behaviour I guess.